# ReportView sem DataSet

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2013, crystal-reports, reportviewer

Estou terminando o meu TCC e tenho uma dúvida referente aos Relatórios com o `ReportView` do Visual Studio 2013.
Vou explicar basicamente com funciona a minha aplicação.

A conexão com o banco de dados é feita através de uma `ConnectionString` declarada no arquivo de configuração do aplicativo. 
Ex.:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<appSettings>
    <add key="conexao" value="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=BD;User ID=admin;Password=admin" />
</appSettings>
<startup> 
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
</startup>
```

Essa `ConnectionString` é dinâmica, ou seja, a aplicação pode conectar ao banco com diferentes usuários e diferentes servidores de Base dados. A edição da `ConnectionString` é feita pelo código abaixo recebendo os do Form de Logon que são passadas as variaveis "server, user e senha":

```
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
config.AppSettings.Settings.Remove("conexao");
config.AppSettings.Settings.Add("conexao", "Data Source=" + server + ";Initial Catalog=BD;User ID=" + user + ";Password=" + senha);
config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
```

E o SqlConnection é declarado conforme abaixo:

```
SqlConnection cx=new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["conexao"]);
```

O problema é que eu não sei se tem como montar o Relatório usando essa conexão com SQL, ou seja, sem montar um DataSet.
Ou se há alguma maneira de carregar o conteúdo de um DataGridView no ReportView e assim montar o Relatório?

Answer (score 1):

Primeiramente caso voce esteja trabalhando com o crystal report, recomendo que voce veja algum tutorial, até porque ele é um pouco complicado de se utilizar.

Vou te passar um exemplo que utilizo e poderá ser muito util para seu aprendizado...

Primeiramente eu recomendo que voce utilize datasets...
Já tive muitos problemas com objetos...

### Tela inicial...

[image: tela1]

```
private void btnImprimir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            List<object> ListParams = new List<object>();

            ListParams.Add(dtpPeriodoInicio.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
            ListParams.Add(dtpPeriodoFinal.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
            ListParams.Add(Convert.ToInt32(String.IsNullOrEmpty(ucTxtBtnFornecedor.TextComponent) ? "0" : ucTxtBtnFornecedor.TextComponent));
            ListParams.Add(Convert.ToInt32(String.IsNullOrEmpty(ucTxtBtnProduto.TextComponent) ? "0" : ucTxtBtnProduto.TextComponent));

            frmPreviewCompra frmPreviewAnalitica = new frmPreviewCompra("RelatorioConferenciaComprasAnalitica", ListParams);
            frmPreviewAnalitica.ShowDialog();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            UIErrors.ShowErrors("Erro ao tentar realizar a impressão.\nErro: " + ex.Message, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

### Tela Preview

Nesta tela voce deve ter o componente CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.CrystalReportViewer

```
public partial class frmPreviewCompra : Form
{
    #region Attributes
    string _tipoRelatorio;
    List<object> _param;
    #endregion Attributes

    #region Constructors
    public frmPreviewCompra()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Construtor do form de visualização do relatório. É necessário passar a sequência
    /// correta de valores na variável Param, pois ela é um array de object na qual no load
    /// do form eu carrego esses valores do array para os parametros do relatório.
    /// 
    /// Obs: Caso for passado errado o relatório sairá errado as informações.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="TipoRelatorio">Define o tipo de relatório que será carregado</param>
    /// <param name="Param">Array com os parametros do relatório</param>
    public frmPreviewCompra(string TipoRelatorio, List<object> Param) : this()
    {
        this._tipoRelatorio = TipoRelatorio;
        this._param = Param;
    }
    #endregion Constructors

    #region Form Events
    private void frmPreviewCompra_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string where = String.Empty, fields = String.Empty, join = String.Empty, orderBy = String.Empty;

        switch (_tipoRelatorio)
        {
            case "RelatorioConferenciaComprasAnalitica":
                dsCompras dsRelCompras = new dsCompras();
                crRelatorioConferenciaComprasAnalitico crComprasAnalitico = new crRelatorioConferenciaComprasAnalitico();

                fields = @"empresa.RazaoLst,
                           concat(nf_entrada.IDParceiroFornec, ' - ', parceiro.Nome) Fornecedor,
                           nf_entrada.NumeroNota NroNotaEntrada,
                           nf_entrada.DataEmissao,
                           nf_entrada.DataEntrada,
                           nf_entrada_produto.IDProduto,
                           produto.Descricao DescricaoProduto,
                           nf_entrada_produto.QtdeProduto,
                           nf_entrada_produto.TotalLiquido,
                           (nf_entrada_produto.TotalLiquido / nf_entrada_produto.QtdeProduto) PrecoMedio";

                join = @"join parceiro on parceiro.ID = nf_entrada.IDParceiroFornec
                         join nf_entrada_produto on nf_entrada_produto.IDNFEntrada = nf_entrada.ID
                         join produto on produto.ID = nf_entrada_produto.IDProduto
                         join empresa on empresa.ID = nf_entrada.IDEmpresa";

                where = @"nf_entrada.DataEntrada between '" + _param[0] + "' and '" + _param[1] + "'" +
                        " AND (((" + Convert.ToInt32(_param[2]) + " > 0) AND (coalesce(nf_entrada.IDParceiroFornec, 0) = " + Convert.ToInt32(_param[2]) + ")) OR ((" + Convert.ToInt32(_param[2]) + " = 0) AND (coalesce(nf_entrada.IDParceiroFornec, 0) >= 0)))" +
                        " AND (((" + Convert.ToInt32(_param[3]) + " > 0) AND (coalesce(nf_entrada_produto.IDProduto, 0) = " + Convert.ToInt32(_param[3]) + ")) OR ((" + Convert.ToInt32(_param[3]) + " = 0) AND (coalesce(nf_entrada_produto.IDProduto, 0) >= 0)))";

                orderBy = "Fornecedor";

                dsRelCompras.Tables["dtRelatorioCompraAnalitica"].Merge(Metodos_NF_Entrada.GetAllNotaFiscalEntrada(fields, where, join, orderBy, "", true));

                crComprasAnalitico.SetDataSource(dsRelCompras.Tables["dtRelatorioCompraAnalitica"]);

                CrystalDecisions.Shared.ParameterField pComprasDataEntradaIni = new CrystalDecisions.Shared.ParameterField();
                CrystalDecisions.Shared.ParameterField pComprasDataEntradaFin = new CrystalDecisions.Shared.ParameterField();
                CrystalDecisions.Shared.ParameterField pComprasFornecedor = new CrystalDecisions.Shared.ParameterField();
                CrystalDecisions.Shared.ParameterField pComprasProduto = new CrystalDecisions.Shared.ParameterField();

                pComprasDataEntradaIni = crComprasAnalitico.ParameterFields["@DataIni"];
                pComprasDataEntradaFin = crComprasAnalitico.ParameterFields["@DataFin"];
                pComprasFornecedor = crComprasAnalitico.ParameterFields["@Fornecedor"];
                pComprasProduto = crComprasAnalitico.ParameterFields["@Produto"];

                pComprasDataEntradaIni.CurrentValues.AddValue(Convert.ToDateTime(_param[0]).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));
                pComprasDataEntradaFin.CurrentValues.AddValue(Convert.ToDateTime(_param[1]).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));
                pComprasFornecedor.CurrentValues.AddValue(_param[2].ToString());
                pComprasProduto.CurrentValues.AddValue(_param[3].ToString());

                crViewerCompras.ReportSource = crComprasAnalitico;
                break;

            case "RelatorioConferenciaComprasSintetica":

                break;
        }
    }
    #endregion Form Events
}
```

### Data Sets

Utilizo varios Projects para separar bem os relatorior por tipo... dentro dele tenho 1 dataset e a tela do relatorio em si.

[image: tela3]
[image: tela2]

### Relatorio

Agora e so adicionar o dataset no relatorio e pronto!

[image: tela4]

Caso tenha problemas relacionados ao visual do relatorio em si... seria recomendavel criar outra pergunta e nos avisar deixando um comentario novo aqui com o link.

Qualquer duvida deixe um comentario...

Comment: fiz uma outr pergunta que tenho duvida, segue o link: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/35519/preencher-dataset-com-datatable

Comment: Ariel... e exatamente isso que faço no exemplo.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode trabalhar com objetos. Você vai precisar, lá no report (rdlc), criar o DataSet, porém, no momento da criação, você irá indicar Object. Para isso, é preciso que você tenha uma classe somente com os campos (propriedades) da sua tabela.

Feito isso, no form que chama o rdlc, você faz o binding através de uma lista.

Exemplo:

VendaPerdidaMLLBindingSource.DataSource = listaVendaPerdida;

Perceba que eu estou passando uma lista para o DataSource. Esta lista é do mesmo tipo da que criou lá no dataset do rdlc.

Se precisar, eu detalho mais a minha explicação

Comment: obrigado pela resposta. Poderia detalhar melhor?

Comment: No meu caso realizo a consulta ao banco de dados, e o método responsável por isso me retorna uma DataTable. Posso indicar esta tabela como o DataSource para o Report? Ex.: meRelatorio.DataSource = tabela;