# Preencher DataSet com DataTable

Tags: c#, sql, .net, datatable, ado.net

No C#, como posso declarar e preencher um DataSet com um DataTable?

Minha ideia é passar os dados resultantes de uma consulta no Banco de Dados para o DataSet, em seguida preencher um Report com esse DataSet.

É possível?

Comment: Sim, é completamente possível. O que você já conseguiu até agora?

Comment: Leia isto e coloque sua pergunta no padrão da comunidade: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ao invés de você preencher o *DataSet* com um *DataTable* e depois passar para o *ReportViewer*, você simplesmente pode utilizar o *ReportDataSource*.

Adicione a seguinte referência:

```
using Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms;
```

Código de exemplo:

```
//dt - deve ser substituido pelo nome do seu DataTable

ReportDataSource dsReport = new ReportDataSource("dataSource", dt);
reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(dsReport);
reportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

Esperto ter ajudado.

Comment: anos depois vi a sua resposta. E foi exatamente assim que fiz. :D

Comment: hahaha, perfeito!!
Forte abraço e boa sorte brother

Answer (score 3):

A classe DataSet possui uma propriedade chamada <strike>Bobby</strike> [Tables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.data.dataset.tables(v=vs.110).aspx). Essa propriedade é uma coleção de tabelas.

Assim sendo, basta chamar o método `Add` da coleção. Assim:

```
using System.Data;

/* .. SNIP .. */

DataSet foo = new DataSet();
DataTable bar = new DataTable();

/* .. SNIP .. */

foo.Tables.Add(bar);
```

E pronto :)

Se ainda tiver alguma dúvida, o pessoal da MSDN tem um tutorial:

[**Adicionando um DataTable a um DataSet**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/aeskbwf7(v=vs.110).aspx)

Note que o método `Add` possui sobrecargas. A que usei aqui recebe uma tabela já pronta. As demais sobrecargas geram a tabela pra você. Confira as quatro sobrecargas do método neste link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.data.datatablecollection.add(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Renan, neste caso eu posso usar este DataSet para preencher o ReportViewer?

Comment: @ArielCardoso, em casos como o seu a pergunta mais importante a fazer é: por que não? :D Falando sério agora, nunca usei o ReportViewer, mas se tudo que ele espera é um DataSet, deve funcionar sim.